# WP Admin Panel for Multi-site install not loading JavaScript for one Subdomain

Tags: multisite, wp-admin

I have deployed a Multi-site WP install using subdomains.  Recently, I used Domain Name Mapping to point one subdomain to a different address.  The frontend is loading fine, but on the WP admin panel there are two strange script files in a row that are trying to load and only on this single domain.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://newdomain.coms?ver=1.6.4"></script>
```

When I am looking at the primary domain for the multi-site install the only two scripts that I see with the same version number 1.6.4 load like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://primarydomain.com/wp-content/mu-plugins/force-strong-passwords/force-zxcvbn.min.js?ver=1.6.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://primarydomain.com/wp-content/mu-plugins/force-strong-passwords/js-admin.min.js?ver=1.6.4"></script>
```

Is there any reason for this to occur only on a single sub-domain?

Answer (score 0):

This appeared to be a very strange bug coming from either my laptop or my network connection.  I ended up turning on my VPN and I was able to access everything normally.  Hopefully this helps if anybody else runs into this strange issue.